# Z-Index all Video types

Tags: css, video, embed, z-index

Is there a way to make it so any embedded video is z-index:-1000; with CSS? Regardless if it has a class or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a rule for any `<embed>` or `<object>` tags to have said property, assuming that there will never be any videos in other tags.

```
embed, object {
    z-index: -1000 !important; /* To override any other styles */
}
```